# Div Overlapping With Another Div

Tags: html, css

i add a image in my container after this when i create another div it overlapping each other i want second div visible below container div

this is html

```
<header>
    <div class="top_nav">

    </div>
</header>
    <div class="container">
    <img src="cover.jpg">
    <div id="short-des">

</div>
</div>
<div class="details">
</div>
```

css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top_nav{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    height: 638px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.container img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 638px;
}

.details{
    height: 638px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;

}
```

i want div name detail to show below the container div

Comment: you have given details container position absolute, remove it if you want the default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7kgq580r/)):

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.top_nav{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: relative;
}

.container{
    height: 638px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.container img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 638px;
    display: block;
}

.details{
    height: 638px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="top_nav">
        top nav
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
    <div id="short-des">
       short descr
    </div>
</div>
<div class="details">
    details
</div>
```

Comment: i give container div position absolute because i want image to start from the top to see over the menu bar

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c097pxL/)

```
.container{
    height: 638px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: center;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.details{
    height: 638px;
    width: 100%;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

removed the position:absolute property

Comment: i give container div position absolute because i want image to start from the top to see over the menu bar i if remove position absolute it make my image to display below to menubar

Comment: alternatively you can put image inside top-bar? no?

Comment: Not sure why you want this but you can try `position: relative` and `z-index` to put image over the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top-nav">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


<section class="section-one">
    <div class="continer">
        <div class="image-outer"><img src="your-image">
        </div>


        <div class="your-title">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: <heder> should be <header>. Also please format your code.